# R gotcha: `.packages()` vs `(.packages())`

Tags: r

I am wrapping my head around this:

```
> .packages()
> (.packages())
[1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"
```

How is it possible that the first command outputs nothing and the second one works? I guess this is yet another syntax gotcha of R.

Comment: `(` a function in R. `(` is evaluating the argument parsed to it. compare `(invisible(2+3))` to `invisible(2+3)`. Then check `.packages` and see what it returns in `return`. To wrap it up just look into `?.packages` and `?"("`

Answer (score 5):

From the help page for `.packages`

```
 ‘.packages()’ returns the names of the currently attached packages
 _invisibly_ whereas ‘.packages(all.available = TRUE)’ gives
 (visibly) _all_ packages available in the library location path
 ‘lib.loc’.
```

Read the help page on `invisible` for more info but basically if something is returned invisibly then it won't automatically print.  It will still be there so you can store it into an object it just won't display by default.  Here are a few other examples

```
> 3
[1] 3
> invisible(3)
> x <- invisible(3)
> x
[1] 3
```

We see that when wrapped in invisible the "3" doesn't automatically print.  We still can store it into an object even when it's invisible though.

Edit: Note that using invisible only masks the printing when the result would be autoprinted by the interpreter.  We can force it to print using print or pretty much any other function call (of which `(` counts as a function which is why wrapping the command in parenthesis prints the result).

```
> invisible(3) + 0
[1] 3
> I(invisible(3))
[1] 3
> (invisible(3))
[1] 3
> print(invisible(3))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks! But the contraituitive gotcha is that `(invisible(3))` is visible again...

Comment: @TMS Added some info at the end